# Why do wildcard resources fail to work when defining secrets policy access?

Tags: terraform, aws-secrets-manager

I have the following terraform policy which allows access to all secrets (using `jsonencode({})` and have trimmed the code for better readability):

```
{
    Action    = [ "secretsmanager:DescribeSecret", "secretsmanager:List*", "secretsmanager:Get*" ]
    Effect    = "Allow",
    Resource  = [
       "arn:aws:secretsmanager:${var.aws_region}:${var.aws_account_id_dev}:*",
    ]
}
```

This works fine, but when I try to limit the scope of the `Resource`s it's not working as expected:

```
{
    Action    = [ "secretsmanager:DescribeSecret", "secretsmanager:List*", "secretsmanager:Get*" ]
    Effect    = "Allow",
    Resource  = [
      "arn:aws:secretsmanager:${var.aws_region}:${var.aws_account_id_dev}:dev/AWS_*",
      "arn:aws:secretsmanager:${var.aws_region}:${var.aws_account_id_dev}:dev/MAIL_*",
      // .. etc
    ]
}
```

My assumption is that the above should allow access to `dev/AWS_KEY`, `dev/AWS_SECRET`, `dev/AWS_WHATEVER` and the same for the `MAIL_*`. I'm not entirely sure what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You left out part of the ARN. When you just had `*` there it didn't matter, but once you start making it more specific, you need to be aware of [the ARN format](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/getting-started.html):

> An Amazon Resource Name (ARN) with the following format:
>
> `arn:aws:secretsmanager:<Region>:<AccountId>:secret:SecretName-6RandomCharacters`

You left out the `:secret` part of the ARN.

I believe your code needs to look like this:

```
{
    Action    = [ "secretsmanager:DescribeSecret", "secretsmanager:List*", "secretsmanager:Get*" ]
    Effect    = "Allow",
    Resource  = [
      "arn:aws:secretsmanager:${var.aws_region}:${var.aws_account_id_dev}:secret:dev/AWS_*",
      "arn:aws:secretsmanager:${var.aws_region}:${var.aws_account_id_dev}:secret:dev/MAIL_*",
      // .. etc
    ]
}
```

Comment: Lol... well that was stupid of me indeed! Thanks! :D